# Laravel Auth extend redirect if unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

I'm authorizing my users using the Cognito Hosted UI from a custom guard. However the only way I can get the user redirected to the Hosted UI is by setting the `headers` myself, like so:

```php
header("Location: https://{$this->domain}/login?scope=email+openid&$query");
exit;
```

However this is the wrong way to redirect within Laravel. If I attempt to use `redirect()->away()` then nothing happens, my protected page gets loaded regardless.

Here is my `authenticate` method, removed the rest of the code as it's irrelevant:

```php
// CognitoUserProvider.php

public function authenticate()
{
    redirect()->away("https://{$this->domain}/login?scope=email+openid&$query");
}
```

```php
// AuthServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    
    Auth::extend('cognito', static function () {
        return new CognitoUserProvider();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add `return`. Like `return redirect()->away("https://{$this->domain}/login?scope=email+openid&$query");`

Comment: @aceraven777 tried that too, doesn't work :(

Comment: Why are you putting the redirect in the UserProvider Auth::extend? By default Laravel is using `auth` middleware to redirect if user is not authenticated. Why not create a custom middleware instead to redirect?